# Run Substrate-node-template with wss and secure rpc

Tags: substrate-node-template, rpc, wss, https

I was running substrate node template with non secure ws connection . After integrating with pallet-evm,pallet-ethereum and other precompiles , I wanted to connect to metamask with `secure rpc connection (https)` but all i get was `http rpc connection` and `ws connection` for interacting with polkadot explorer . So is there a way to connect to polkadot explorer with `wss connection` and metamask with `https rpc` connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to proxy it behind a proxy-ing webserver (for example nginx) since the node itself cannot provide a valid certificate. More info can be found on the [polkadot wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-wss). For nginx you can add the following (in an ssl enabled  virtal host), assuming the node rpc port is 9944:

```
server {   
    (...)   
    location / {
    proxy_buffers 16 4k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9944;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;    
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot